# Simple Choice field value assignment

Tags: development, choice-field

My apologies for asking, what seems like, a really basic question - but I can't appear to assign a value to a 'Choice' field programmatically and can't find anything documented anywhere.

Defined in my xml as:

```
 <Field Type="Choice" DisplayName="MyChoiceField" StaticName="MyChoiceField" Name="MyChoiceField"
       ID="[GUID]" Format="Dropdown" FillInChoice="FALSE" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE"  >
    <Default></Default>
    <CHOICES>
      <CHOICE>Choice1</CHOICE>
      <CHOICE>Choice2</CHOICE>
    </CHOICES>
  </Field>
```

And my attempted assign as:

```
item["MyChoiceField"] = "Choice1";
```

But I'm getting the exception that this is an invalid value for a choice field.

Comment: Thanks for your flag, but can you edit your post to avoid any possible confusion? Many thanks. - mod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [GetFieldValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.getfieldvalue.aspx) method of the field class if you are unsure of the actual type of the underling value.

For example:

```
item["MyChoiceField"] = listIstance.Fields["MyChoiceField"].GetFieldValue("Choice1");
```

Comment: This worked (hence marked as answer) about 3 hours ago, now it does not!? "A look-up field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try again." By the way - in this instance - GetFieldValue is returning a string - would it not be effectively the same to just assign the string "Choice1" directly?

Comment: Umm - need more info - can you add the caml from the field declaration to the question?

Comment: Not sure where I'd get CAML for the field declaration or what it's used for sorry. Is it used to define the field?

Comment: My problems were completely misplaced here. It was another column that was causing the issue. Thanks a lot for all of your input anyway.

Answer (score 1):

maybe somthing like this?

```
// Get a reference to the field.
SPFieldMultiChoice choiceField = (SPFieldMultiChoice)list.Fields.GetField(fieldInternalName);

// Create a field value with all choices selected.
// (A CheckBoxChoiceField control would have all boxes checked.)
SPFieldMultiChoiceValue values = new SPFieldMultiChoiceValue();
foreach (string choice in choices)
{
   values.Add(choice);
}

// Add an item to the list.
SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title] = "Test item";
item[choiceField.Id] = values;
item.Update();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldmultichoicevalue.aspx